# Powershell - Add users to groups without ansi

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am looking for a solution to add users to groups in active directory after I have created their users accounts. Currently my powershell script has a few things lacking but I am going to tackle them one at a time.

In this cycle I trying to learn the best way to add groups to newly created user accounts. Is it best to copy from a template account (which I am having problems doing as I keep getting a blank account... Or should I manage all new user information directly in the script.  Which is best practice?

In my research I see how this can be done with adsi.

I was hoping not to use this method unless I have to. what I was hoping for was something like this. with `Get-ADUser`, `Set-ADUser`, `Set-ADObject`, `Get-ADObject`, or similar commands.

```
$user=get-aduser 'abc user'
$userModify=Set-aduser $user

$groups=get-aduser $tmplateUser | select -ExpandProperty memberof
```

`#` or `groups` could come from an array, I have not decided which is best.

```
foreach ($Group In $groups) 
{
   $usermodify.memberof.add -identity $Group -member $user
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or examples?

Answer (score 1):

if you can use the 'ActiveDirectory' module then you can try:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```

This will show you the cmdlets available for managing groupmembership.

```
 Get-Command -Verb add -Noun *group*
```

This will show you examples of the cmdlet.

```
Help cmdletname -examples
```

There are many ways to create users, most use information stored in a csv file as input to say a cmdlet like `New-ADUser`.

The `foreach` construct will depend upon which cmdlet you choose to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
$groups = Get-ADUser $tmplateUser -Properties memberof | 
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof

foreach ($group in $groups)
{
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $newuser
}
```